# Is there a way to access all user info?

Tags: user-management, user-record

Is there a way to get a drill down through DB/reports all the info related to an user
like

1. permission set
2. sharing settings
3. active/inactive( I can get this by Isactive filter)
4. what public groups he/she is associated with ?
5. what is the role of the user etc..

Please advice.

UPDATE June 21 ,2013: This question has surfaced are there any third party apps that would let me see a overall view of what the user is associated with?

Comment: Is your intention to do this natively within Salesforce or externally via another tool? A lot of that information can be extracted with the APIs and then manipulated and presented as required.

Comment: Daniel I can at the end of the day build a VF consolidate all the data I want and display it as required but was curious if someone took that extra pain :|

Answer (score 3):

1. Permission sets are readable (and writable) from within apex via the `PermissionSet` and `PermissionSetAssignment` sObjects.
2. sharing settings are not currently readable via apex officially. You can do some basic detection by checking if the related Share sObject exists, if so the object is not set to public read/write, but getting more detail than that requires the metadata api (not accessible in apex).
3. Available from the user sObject via the isActive field as you mentioned.
4. This is available by querying the `Group` and `GroupMember` sObjects. Group itself has a number of types, so you'll want to filter this most likely. See: [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) and look at the values for the `Type` field.
5. This is available from the `role` field on the user sObject, which relates to a `Group` sObject with a `Type` of "Role".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's feasible without using some API/Apex. Especially not available in reports or list views.

Comment: marking as unsolved since I wanted to know if there are third party apps that could help me get this done. If I do not get any answers I will switch it back to solved.