# Determine the "why" for records in UserRecordAccess

Tags: apex, sharing

I have queried the UserRecordAccess table previously to determine a user's permission for records.

Is there a way to go one step further and determine why the values are what they are?

For example, if a user has access to account ABC I would like to find out which Profile, Sharing Rule, etc. was responsible for enabling access.

Comment: A bit wide question to give an answer, I asked something similar http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/is-there-a-way-to-access-all-user-info but as of today I dont think you can grab all easily. You may have to write too much code for getting this basic info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserRecordAccess does not tell you why a user has access, for its purpose is to tell you the user's effective access level without the hassle of checking a half-dozen different objects to determine a user's effective level.

Sharing is determined by the least restrictive of:

- Organization Wide Defaults
- Explicit Sharing
- Ownership
- Role Hierarchy
- Permission Sets
- Profile Permissions
- Sharing Rules

The user might have several reasons why they have a particular level of access (e.g. a sharing rule plus role hierarchy). You can query most of the other settings to determine why, if you really need to.